# How could I sync ONLY my calendar with Gmail (optionally when a WiFi connection is available)?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, gmail, calendar

On my old Nokia C5, there was a quite smart setting to sync the phone calendar with my Gmail calendar when a WiFi connection was available, every say 30 minutes (using [MailForExchange](http://store.ovi.com/content/289487)).

I'd expected that a tightly-Google-coupled system like Android would do that task even better, but it doesn't (or I wasn't able to figure out how).

First of all, automatic synchronizing is disabled because I don't want to sync contacts, images, mails, whatever. **Only my calendar!**

I know that I could sync the calendar when I go to Settings → Accounts and Synchronisation → tip on my Google account → scroll to the calendar entry → sync now.

But that's **that** deep hidden in menus that it is not really fun.

Is there a way to have a shortcut on the home screen that I could use to directly start synchronizing **only** my calendar with one tip?

If automatic synchronisation with WiFi could be set up (once again: only my calendar), that would be an *extra bonus*.

**My main aim is to sync only the calendar, nothing else.**

Comment: Nice question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: To **only** sync the calendar you first have to switch off everything else:
Go to *Settings -> Accounts -> YOUR Google Account*
and un-check all the sync targets you don't want (Chrome, GMail, Drive, Contacts, ...)
/EDIT

Then you can take care of **when** to have it sync.
Generally, this is left to 3rd party apps.

You can always pick your favourite 3rd-party app to get that feature, and there is a ton of it. Some samples:

- [JuiceDefender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Latedroid) (free/plus/ultimate/beta, you'll probably have to buy ultimate for the feature you want)
- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=related_apps)
- [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) (not sure if it supports your use case)
- or just search Google Play for 'profile sync schedule' (or similar)

The latter two examples are somewhat complicated to set up but are very powerful. I'd try JuiceDefender.

Comment: Tasker? Complicated? Not if the profile is already provided :) If you like that, check my answer #-)

Comment: I actually have bought tasker but haven't yet found the time to dive into it (mostly due to laziness and not knowing *where to start*)

Comment: I got the free copy (7 day trial) to start with. On the 4th day I bought it. Never regretted! So you see: took me about 3 days for a "basic start". So admitted, it's not easy -- but once you've got the idea... Btw: There are some nice tutorials around to get you started...

Comment: It's now included.

Answer (score 4):

Too complicated. There are lots of automation apps available on the market which you could use to toggle this stuff depending on the connection available. My favorite again here: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). You could create a profile, and call it e.g. "AutoSync":

**Condition:** State->Wifi: Wifi Connected
**Task:** Auto-Sync: Turn On
**Exit:** Auto-Sync: Turn Off

Once set up, you can forget about it -- *Tasker* takes care for it automatically.

Afterword: Though Tasker is *my* favorite, it might not be the easiest solution for everybody. Takes some time to get used to it, costs some 5 Euro -- but is really worth both: no other tool gives you so many possibilities and flexibility. If that's too heavy for you, there are some alternatives available: Check the playstore e.g. for [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), and also watch out for the "other users also installed..." part of the pages.

Oh: If you insist on an *optional* widget for your *homescreen* (that's what the "desktop" is usually called here), *Tasker* allows you to create them for its tasks as well...

Comment: This would take care of sync globally though (not only  calendar sync), right?

Comment: Yepp. The other one as well, though: Whether you have some widget you tap, or have the setting switched automatically. AFAIK currently there's no way to do that on a per-app-basis. Hm, should be possible on routed phones via iptables...

Comment: @ce4 thanks for mentioning this. The main feature I'm seraching for is to sync only the calendar. Automation of that process would be an extra gimmick (see updated question)

Comment: Oh, that should be easy: Go to settings, Accounts, YOUR Google Account and un-check all the sync targets you don't want  (chrome, gmail, drive, contacts, ...)